# Windows TeX editor with live preview

Tags: editors, preview

I'm looking for a TeX editor for Windows that would offer a live preview of fully-rendered PDFs, like what [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) does on Mac OS - preferably freeware, but if such an editor is payware, I'm interested in that, too. So far, this search has turned up nothing, including the other answers on this site.

Has anyone heard of this kind of functionality in an editor? Are there plugins for existing editors that allow for this?

Comment: Bakoma may help you.

Comment: Not quite a live preview, but latexdaemon updates the pdf in the viewer each time you save the source. Works with latex, pdflatex,dvips. See here: http://william.famille-blum.org/software/latexdaemon/index.html